# Using your own page fault handler

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, x86-64

I want to add code to the page fault handler in Linux, especially I'm interested in modifying the one used for copy on write, that is `do_wp_page`. However, the dilemma is that the machine I want to test my applications is not in my control. The OS or the kernel cannot be modified on that machine, as it is a shared machine used by several users.

Now I'm looking for a way I can define my own page fault handler, that will only be used for the applications I'm running. Maybe I could use a kernel module (I would have to ask for some administrative rights for that too I think) or maybe I can define it in user-space. And please notice that I don't want it for handling SIGSEGV signals, so don't say to use `mprotect`. I want to handle real copy on write page faults. What are my options here?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the easiest thing to do would be to use a virtual machine - doing you kernel-level development in a VM means errors won't cause problems for other users.

Comment: But I cannot benchmark properly in VM. I need to benchmark my applications.

Comment: @user1018562 If you need to benchmark, then a shared machine isn't suitable anyway - other users will produce too much noise in your readings.

Comment: Sure you can. You can do benchmarks relative to the original page fault handler. Besides, while developing the new one you *will* crash the kernel, so don't even try to do it on a shared machine

Comment: @KristofProvost - I suppose it's possible to do benchmarks on a shared machine, but you need to collect a lot more samples, so that you can differentiate other users' activities from your code differences. It makes your life *much* harder. And certainly doing it in a VM on a shared machine isn't going to be much harder than on a shared machine directly.

Comment: I obviously benchmark when the machine is idle, which it is quite a lot of time. Only few users are authorized to use that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately do_page_fault and do_wp_page address is not exposed so any way of actually doing what you say is probably frowned upon. Do development on the shared machine on a VM and then get a dedicated machine to handle your benchmarks. Shared machine won't give you good readings anyway as other users workloads will interfere with yours anyway.

Side-note: What's wrong with COW on Linux anyway that you need to modify it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with COW. I just need to add code to know which pages are being duplicated. At least can we get to know which pages are being copied on write?

Comment: I believe that time (certain versions of the time command at least) will tell you how many page faults are incurred and how many of them are COW

Comment: I don't want mere numbers but also the addresses of the pages copied.

Comment: @user1018562, you should be able to achieve this using perf or systemtap.